# locate function with regular expression in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to locate the position of a character matching some regular expression in SQL query used with spark. Can I use locate function for this?

e.g. `column_value = SM_12456_abc`

```
select locate([a-z], 'SM_12456_abc') as lower_case_presence
```

I expect the position of lowercase `a` as output i.e. `10` but it returns 0 to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`locate` function doesn't support regex. However, you can combine it with [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_extract) function:

```
select locate(regexp_extract('SM_12456_abc', '([a-z])', 1),  'SM_12456_abc') as lower_case_presence
```

`regexp_extract('SM_12456_abc', '([a-z])', 1)` will return first match (`a`in this case) then pass it to `locate` function.

```py
spark.sql("select locate(regexp_extract('SM_12456_abc', '([a-z])', 1),  'SM_12456_abc') as lower_case_presence").show()

#+-------------------+
#|lower_case_presence|
#+-------------------+
#|                 10|
#+-------------------+
```

Comment: What does regexp_extract return if pattern or regex not present? For a try, I used nvl outside it but it shows blank value in dataframe e.g nvl(regexp_extract('123456_HM','([a-z])'), 'missing') but it shows blank cell in df

Comment: @AjayPatil it returns an empty string when not matched `''`

Comment: @blackbishop when I try this solution on a dataframe column it correctly returns the position of the characters for which there is a match in the regex in that column. However, when there isn't a match it returns a 1. Do you know why this is, I would've thought it would return an empty string for rows when there isn't a match rather than a 1.

Comment: @blackbishop For example the following slightly edited version of your example returns a 1 even though there are no lower case letters spark.sql("select locate(regexp_extract('SM_12456_ABC', '([a-z])', 1),  'SM_12456_ABC') as lower_case_presence").show()