# PySpark how to get the position of a list of strings within a column but return a zero if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I've recently started learning PySpark and I'm trying to understand how to return the position of a regex pattern within a column but then if the regex pattern does not exist in the column then to return a 0.

I've tried this other really good answer on StackOverflow which does a great job of returning the position of where a regex pattern starts in another string. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66121409/locate-function-with-regular-expression-in-spark-sql` However, in this answer, when the regex pattern does not exist in the string it returns a 1 instead of what I need which is a 0.

Based on the other answer I've tried to adapt it like below:

```
spark.sql("select locate(regexp_extract('0000X00', '([X,Y,Z,W])', 1),  '0000X00') as check_pos_string").show()

+----------------+
|check_pos_string|
+----------------+
|               5|
+----------------+
```

Which as expected returns the position of 5 which is where the character X from the regex pattern occurs in the string it is checking.

However, when I try the following it returns a 1 even though the pattern doesn't exist within the string it is checking.

```
spark.sql("select locate(regexp_extract('0000000', '([X,Y,Z,W])', 1),  '0000000') as check_pos_string").show()

+----------------+
|check_pos_string|
+----------------+
|               1|
+----------------+
```

Instead of a 1, I would like to know how to return a 0 if the regex pattern doesn't exist in the string so it looks like below.

```
+----------------+
|check_pos_string|
+----------------+
|               0|
+----------------+
```

I have a feeling that I'm misunderstanding something simple due to my lack of experience with PySpark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of general points:

- `[X,Y,Z,W]` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which matches all the characters between the square brackets, this means it matches `X`, `,` `Y`, `,`, `Z`, `,` and `W` (note it's matching the commas too). What you actually want is `[XYZW]` or more concisely `[W-Z]`.
- You don't need a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(...)` in your expression; without one just change the `group` parameter to `0`.

So your call to `regexp_extract` should look like:

```
regexp_extract('0000X00', '[XYZW]', 0)
```

In terms of your problem, this is caused by `regexp_extract` returning an empty string when it doesn't match anything, and `locate` "finding" that string at the beginning of your input and hence returning `1` as the result.

You can work around that by instead *replacing* the match with a character that would not normally occur in the string, and then trying to `locate` that character e.g.

```
spark.sql("select locate('*', regexp_replace('0000X0Y', '[W-Z]', '*')) as check_pos_string").show()
```

Output:

| check_pos_string |
| --- |
| 5 |

When the match is not found, the special character will not be replaced into the string and so `locate` will return `0`:

```
spark.sql("select locate('*', regexp_replace('0000000', '[W-Z]', '*')) as check_pos_string").show()
```

Output:

| check_pos_string |
| --- |
| 0 |

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks so much I was stuck on this for hours trying different variations! I really appreciate your explanation about the regex too as this is something I always find hard to get my head around. Actually, in my data there are different characters that don't run sequentially but I did them in the way you described without commas and without () and it worked nicely, e.g. [BXDM].

Comment: @data101 That's great to hear. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

From what i can see, there is no way to change behaviour of regexp_exctract, but there is a workaround. You can use IF statement and return 0 when there is no match

```
spark.sql(
  "SELECT CASE WHEN regexp_extract('0000000', '([X,Y,Z,W])', 1) = '' THEN 0 ELSE locate(regexp_extract('0000000', '([X,Y,Z,W])', 1), '0000000') END AS check_pos_string"
).show()
```